# How to create a filereading program that loads a file of codes

Tags: c++, fstream

Basically my program is giving me a load of errors with my filereading program when trying to compile. The **goal is to get the user to enter the threshold number** and the **strings that are equal to or greater than that threshold number will be outputted**. The program fails at that because there are several errors with the code. How to fix the errors within the code?

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   using namespace std;
  
   int read_airports(string cities[], int threshold);
  
   int main()
  {
      ifstream fin;
 
      fin.open("airports.txt");
 
      if (fin.is_open())
      {
          string cities[20];
          int count, threshold;
 
          count = read_airports(cities, threshold);
          while(!fin.eof())
          {
          fin >> threshold;
          cout << "Enter a threshold number" << endl;
          cin >> threshold;
 
          if (fin.good())
          {
              if (cities >= threshold)
              {
                  cout << cities << endl;
              }
          }

          }
          fin.close();
      }
 
      return 0;
  }
 
 
  int read_airports(string cities[], int threshold)
  {
  }
```

Here is the text file where this code is based off of.

```
LAX Los-Angeles 40
JFK New-York 39
IAH Houston 26
LCY London 34
PAR Paris 15
TYO Tokyo 11
SEL Seoul 5
YYZ Toronto 28
```

Comment: Some say that the most important part of a question on stackoverflow.com would be an actual question. Some say that a question is always the most important part of a question, whether it's posted on Stackoverflow or not. Your question does not appear to include any question at all, though. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: ***Basically my program is giving me a load of errors with my filereading program when trying to compile.*** My advice is to make sure you look at the errors in file order so that the first error appears first. A single error can trigger multiple reports.

Answer (score 1):

**[Warning: none of this code has been tested at all.]**

I would structure the code rather differently.

I would create a structure for the data about each airport/city:

```cpp
struct airport {
    std::string abbreviation;
    std::string city_name;
    int threshold;
};
```

Then I'd overload `operator>>` to read one of those records from a stream, and `operator<<` to write one to a stream:

```cpp
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, airport &ap) {
    return is >> ap.abbreviation >> ap.city_name >> ap.threshold;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, airport const &ap) {
    return os << ap.abbreviation << "\t" << ap.city_name << "\t" << ap.threshold;
}
```

Then I'd write code to desired data from a file of those to standard output:

```cpp
std::ifstream infile("airportdata.txt");
std::cout << "Please enter minimum threshold value: ";
int threshold;
std::cin >> threshold;

std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<airport>(infile), {}, 
             std::ostream_iterator<airport>(std::cout, "\n"),
             [=](airport const &ap) { return ap.threshold > threshold; });
```